# What's the difference between normal opcodes and opcodes with their MSB set?

Tags: lua, virtual-machine, opcodes

What's the difference between normal opcodes and opcodes with their MSB (Most Significant Bit) set?

Example:

```
0036  5E000001           [4] return     1   2
003A  1E008000           [5] return     0   1
```

The first opcode (0x5E/1011110) has its MSB set and the second opcode (0x1E/0011110) hasn't.

Edit: Corrected 'byte' to 'bit', duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling, I found a header of the Lua source ([lopcodes.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html)) explaining the instruction format a bit better.

It looks like it's wrong to read the opcode as a byte, it should be read as 6 bits:

```
All instructions have an opcode in the first 6 bits.
Instructions can have the following fields:
`A' : 8 bits
`B' : 9 bits
`C' : 9 bits
`Bx' : 18 bits (`B' and `C' together)
`sBx' : signed Bx
```

Comment: Did you read this doc? http://luaforge.net/docman/view.php/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't really explain it though. Edit: I reread some parts and noticed this: "The details can be
found in lopcodes.h, while the Instruction type definition is defined in llimits.h."